# Generating random unsigned char values in C++

Tags: c++, random, unsigned-char

I was wondering how to generate random unsigned char values. My idea;
`rand()%255;` since unsigned chars support between 0-255. I was wondering if this method could be improved(or is it the most legit way to do this)

Comment: Define "improve". BTW you should use `rand()%256`.

Comment: Actually I should edit "improve" I was wondering if this was the right way

Comment: It is the right way. You could also use the random utilities provided in C++11, but this works.

Comment: It also depends on what you intend to use these values for. Are they going to be used as characters (e.g. to form a string that you are going to print or perform other string operations on)? Or are you using them just as an unsigned 8-bit integer?

Comment: I'm running the function in a loop to fill a matrix and most of the signs are "?". I've set the srand as 'srand((unsigned)time(NULL));'

Comment: @rolandbishop : I hope you're not calling `srand` inside the loop...

Comment: Course not, just one time at the very beginning of the program

Comment: Just a note: 0-255 are 256 values, so you probably want `rand() % 256` [or `rand() & 0xFF`].

Answer (score 6):

A lot faster will be simple

```
unsigned char a = (unsigned char) rand();
```

Or you can do even 4 shifts of generated integer (on 32bit architecture) to four times reduce call to `rand()`:

```
int a = rand();
unsigned char r1 = (unsigned char) a;
unsigned char r2 = (unsigned char) a >> 8;
unsigned char r3 = (unsigned char) a >> 16;
unsigned char r4 = (unsigned char) a >> 24;
```

Or something like that.

Comment: since (unsigned char) up there, rand() function won't be going off limits right?

Comment: On platforms for which `RAND_MAX` is less than `INT_MAX` (e.g. VC++ where `RAND_MAX` is `32767`), the high-order bytes will always be `0`.

Comment: The point still comes across. A simple check of whether this is the case beforehand would do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

The C++11 random number library is the best way if you want to stick to the standard library:

```
#include <random>

#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <climits>

int main() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};

    auto rand = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<>(0, UCHAR_MAX),
                          std::mt19937(seed));

    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "), 25, rand);
}
```

The library provides some uniform random number engines and adapters to use with them to produce various distributions. Here we use a `mt19937` engine (seeded using `random_device` (as a source of non-deterministic data if possible), and `seed_seq` to combine enough random data into a form suitable for filling out mt19937's internal state. Then we adapt the `mt19937` using a `uniform_int_distribution`. By default this distribution will produce numbers uniformly distributed across the range supported by its template parameter, in this case `unsigned char`. So the function object we create will produce values in the range [0 256). Its results are demonstrated by writing out 25 values to the standard output.

There are distributions for other uses such as producing a normal distribution, simulating coin flips, or picking items out of a set with arbitrary weights (e.g. picking one of 3 items where the first is picked 50% of the time, the second is picked 10% of the time, and the third, 40% of the time).

Other engines are provided for different quality and performance characteristics. For example if you need a cryptographic random number generator, random_device may provide it if your implementation offers such capability.

---

[Some](http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/ease-of-use-without-loss-of-power.html) additional [resources](http://www.pcg-random.org/).

Comment: Forgive me im asking a real silly question but this method would also work on g++ too right?

Comment: @rolandbishop Yeah, recent versions of gcc implement the C++11 random library. I tried it with gcc 4.5.1

Comment: `uniform_int_distribution<unsigned char>` gives compile-time error with Visual C++ 2013, so this idea doesn't look like portable one.

Comment: @Vitaliy Thanks, I've fixed that problem.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly cleaner way to do this the C++ way, using the [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) library would be:

```
#include <random>

int myseed = 1234;

std::default_random_engine rng(myseed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> rng_dist(0, 255);
char mychar = static_cast<unsigned char>(rng_dist(rng));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `unsigned char n = (unsigned char)(rand() & 0x00ff);`

Answer (score 0):

And you should be aware that `rand()` is one of the worst of the widely available random number generators, in terms of the quality (randomness) of its output.  On UNIX-based systems, and some others, `random()` and `lrand48()` [and friends] are substantially better.  For speed, the best way to use these is as described by @Pida, above, where you call only once for a word's worth of random bits.  The word size depends on the random number generator you use.